# Print the loop number in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have following simple code (a very simplified version of my actual loop)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(
  [i+333 for i in range(5)]

)
```

However I also want to put some mechanism where the `for` loop also print the value `i`. Something like

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(
  [(i+333) & print(i) for i in range(5)]

)
```

Is there any way to directly assign such instruction in above setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `print(x) or ...`  to the list comprehension.

```
[print(i) or i+333 for i in range(5)]
```

The second half of the `or` condition will always be chosen, because `print()` does not return anything and will always be falsey.

Comment: Very elegant and minimal solution. Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

You can embed a function in the for loop that returns a value. Here is a very quick and simple example which I am sure can be improved on, but as a concept look at the following:

```py
import pandas as pd


def inc_and_print(x):
    v = x + 111
    print(v)
    return v


df = pd.DataFrame(
    [inc_and_print(i) for i in range(5)]
)
print(df)
```

```
111
112
113
114
115
     0
0  111
1  112
2  113
3  114
4  115
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`walrus operator`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/walrus-operator-in-python-3-8/) and do something like that:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame( [(num := i + 333, print(num))[0] for i in range(5)])
```